# How to override case class field with annotation addition?

Tags: scala, annotations, swagger

### Question

How can I override a `case class` with annotation addition? Something like the following:

```scala
case class Foo (
  bar: Int
)

new Foo {
  @Annotation
  override val bar: Int
}
```

In the code above, I try to create an anonymous case class which overrides the field `bar` of the class `Foo` with the annotation `@Annotation`. Compiling returns *"Illegal start of declaration `@Annotation`"*.

### Context

I am trying to create a swagger documentation service but didn't want to litter the whole model classes with swagger annotations. I thought of creating anonymous case classes to be used only in the swagger API path annotations; these anonymous case classes will override the original model classes with swagger annotations.

It is used as something like:

```scala
new ApiImplicitParam(
  name = "body",
  dataTypeClass = classOf[DataType {
    @ApiModelProperty
    override val someEnum: SomeEnum
  }],
  required = true,
  paramType = "body"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because you

- don't provide argument for constructor

and

- don't implement `bar`.

The following code compiles in 2.13

```
new Foo(???) {
  @Annotation
  override val bar: Int = ???
}
```

Comment: @krismath `classOf` is different. With `classOf` you don't create `new` instance.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I fix the bottom example, which uses `classOf`?

Comment: @krismath I guess you can't. Parser will be satisfied with `classOf[(Foo {
       val bar: Int @Annotation
    })]` but this is illegal because `Foo {
       val bar: Int
    }` is not a class type. Moreover I guess Swagger doesn't expect using annotations like that. Anonymous classes have many limitations https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/832 "Allowing annotating anonymous classes requires changing the Scala syntax, which is considered a rather big change.

Since one can always work around it by creating a named class, this won't be added in order to keep the language simpler."